# Exception upon debugging protractor scripts in VSCode

Tags: node.js, debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code, e2e-testing

I'm trying to debug my e2e Protractor scripts in VSCode. However the debugging fails at the beginning with the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error
    at projectpath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:84:11
    at hasStacks (projectpath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:43:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (projectpath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:79:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

My launch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",    
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/e2etests/protractor.conf.js",
                "--suites",
                "dummy"
            ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
```

I'd like to mention, that the testscripts can be started in VSCode smoothly. What could be the root-cause?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with the debug adapter. (But not quite this). The solution was to run the debugger in the integrated console. See if this works for you.

```
"configurations": [        
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",    
        ...
        "console": "integratedTerminal"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disabling the 'All Exceptions' checkbox in 'Breakpoints' window in VSCode